# How to refresh a materialized view as soon as the day gets over in postgres

Tags: postgresql, materialized-views

I'm working on a project which requires me to write a query to create a materialized view in postgres. My requirement is that the materialized view must refresh itself periodically everyday only at 12am. Though I found some information that may be relevant on other places in the web, I wasn't so sure to modify and implement, as it may result to be too costly for me plus i'm not too experienced in sql.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Its how to referesh a materialized view whenever a day changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation states:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-creatematerializedview.html

> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW defines a materialized view of a query. The query is executed and used to populate the view at the time the command is issued (unless WITH NO DATA is used) and may be refreshed later using REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW.

So in order to refresh a Materialized View you will need:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html

`REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW`

In order to to this periodically you will need some kind of [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) implementation.

A Postgresql "inhouse" solution could be: https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron

Comment: it should be worth noting, this package does not seem to be updated very frequently in the repos, currently +1 year out of date. also does not support most modern postgres versions. so please compile directly from source, or use built in cron and just run the SQL directly, which is probably your better option